# SAP B1 GetDate function not showing time

Tags: sql, sapb1

In SAP B1 on SQL Server, I'm using the `GETDATE()` function which should show date and time. It is only showing the date portion for me.

Why might this be? Have had a look around but couldn't find an answer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, this is because of the settings in SAP B1 displaying the value this way. Just need to change the code to reflect this

```
CAST(GetDate() AS VARCHAR)
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Answer (score 0):

OR :) you can use this.

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR ,GetDate()  , 101)

[image]